# MySQL driver type detail

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am using MySQL as my backend and just curious to know that MySQL falls under which driver type in Java, I am confused with type 3 and type 4 driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL Driver is a Type 4. You can find this in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-overview.html):

> MySQL Connector/J is a JDBC Type 4 driver.

I am wondering though why you are asking this: in general it isn't really relevant to know the driver type, and especially wondering about Type 3 is bit weird because they are relatively rare and if you are using Type 3, you'd know it as it requires a separate server/middleware instance to actually connect to the database. See also the [wikipedia JDBC driver entry on Type 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_3_Driver_-_Network-Protocol_Driver.28MiddleWare_Driver.29).